# Large text in default AlertDialog freezes screen

Tags: android, screen, android-alertdialog

I want to display a large message into Default AlertDialog with the following code.

```
public void showConditions(View v)
{
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); 
    alertDialog.setTitle("Policy Terms");
    alertDialog.setMessage("very large text...");
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { alertDialog.cancel(); }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

The code is working fine but shows the dialog after **2 or 3 seconds**,
when I pressed the button and **freezes** the screen too.

I tried to display the text into another new activity and happens the same: 
 - Freeze the screen and takes 2 seconds to display it.

I tried to show a loader(ProgressBar) to inform the user that something is being open soon. 
 - Happens the same.

I can't find another solution.

I would appreciate any ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: Try with a short text ( as message) and see if it freezes the screen too.

Comment: Thanks, and yes with short text it works. but I need to display large text.

Comment: Your code looks ok, so i think the only reason that can cause the freezes is the text length... how many characters in your text?

Comment: It is about 3 pages (22736 characters long). It is the Policy terms text.